# Why do I get a 'Connection timeout'? - And how to fix?

Tags: ssh

I have 2 Pi's and a laptop;

pi.local - Already setup and running, using staic IP and connected through LAN

pi.wifi - Partially setup, causing a problem, which this question is about.

laptop - Macos x Yosemite

When I'm connecting from Laptop to pi.wifi I get a "Connection timeout".

I've tried a number of things, trying to figure out where the error is, but to no avail. 
I've tried the following...

- Using `sudo raspi-config` to enable SSH, and this seems to be working. Reboot after done config - No errors.
- Connecting from laptop to pi.local everything is fine. I get connection and everything works.
- I can connect from pi.wifi to pi.wifi. I've tried connecting to both 127.0.0.1 and the real ip, with no problems. This suggest that the SSH works on pi.wifi
- The odd parts is, that if i connect from laptop to pi.local and use that connection to make a new connection to pi.wifi, everything goes smooth. This confirms that SSH works on pi.wifi
- I've tried to remove the key, using `ssh-keygen -R IP_BE_HERE` from laptop, just to make sure.
- The pi.wifi has no problems getting on the wifi. All my `ping` attempts from pi.wifi to e.g. Google goes through just fine.
- When pinging from pi.local to pi.wifi, everything is fine, but when pinging from laptop to pi.wifi I get a timeout.

My suspicion goes toward some error between laptop and pi.wifi, but I simply cannot put my finger on what could be wrong!

Can someone help get on with this?

Comment: You need to have a look at where packets are going on the network using a tool such as [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html), which is available for OSX and the pi via distro installer (for raspbian, `apt-get`).  It doesn't matter which machine on the LAN you run this on, either of those  or a completely different one (since all traffic on the LAN is actually visible to all machines, this is the nature of networking).

Comment: You may know what you mean by `pi.local` and `pi.wifi` but it is far from clear. `pi.local` looks line the OS X description of a zero conf connection